# Input Redirection to keyboard input

Tags: java, io-redirection

I have a program that uses input redirection, and at some point I want to start giving input from the keyboard. How would I go about re-redirecting input?

I run the program as follows

```
java SomeClass < data.txt
```

The code looks something like this

```
java.util.Scanner  = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
//Process the data from data.txt
//Here I want to be able to receive input from the keyboard, but input still only looks for input from data.txt
```

Is there some way I can go about receiving input from keyboard again using the above method, or  alternatively, what other options exist for receiving input from two different sources?

P.S. I'm using Windows.

Comment: Do you have to use io-redirection? What about just passing the file name as a command line argument and reading the file in your code?

Comment: @copeg I was about to to do that, but for curiosity's sake I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix (including OS X) you should be able to use the `cat` command to combine input from two or more sources, in order, into one stream.  You can then pipe that into your program:

```
cat data.txt - | java SomeClass
```

The bare `-` argument represents the standard input, which is connected to the keyboard in an interactive shell session.

Comment: I'm using windows, any suggestions?

Comment: Windows doesn't ship with anything quite like `cat`.  There's `type`, which is similar, but it doesn't do what you need.  Possibly Powershell has a way to do it, but I'm not immediately turning anything up.  I guess maybe you could create a named pipe, redirect its input into `java`, and copy both `data.txt` and `CON` into it.  A more Windows-y person might have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How about having many inputs and use them whenever you need?

```
Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner("data.txt");
    //Process the data from data.txt
    fileScanner.nextLine();
    //Here I want to be able to receive input from the keyboard, but input still only looks for input 
    keyboardScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Sure, if you want the program to *depend* on that arrangement of inputs, or if you want to give it options to support that.  The point of an I/O redirection approach is that the program doesn't have to have any of that built in.  But with that said, yes, it could work.

Comment: Good. What about providing file name in the command line? Something like >app1 -input1 data.txt -input2 dat.file

Comment: Yes, as I said, the Java program could alternatively accept options by which you can configure such behavior.  That's more flexible than hard-wiring it, but not as good as not having to worry about it at all.